# PowerShell Write-Host $_ Produces no Output Inside a Loop

Tags: powershell, loops, write-host

`$ll = @("a","b","c"); ForEach ($e in $ll) {Write-Host $_}`

I've spent too much time on this already and I'm tired of searching and fiddling. Who wants to make me feel silly by explaining why this PowerShell code produces no output? No errors. Just 3 new blank lines.

Edit: I know what $_ is and what it's supposed to do. It's simply not working in this loop. Thx

Comment: `$_` has a value only in a `ForEach-Object` pipeline. What you have here is a `foreach` loop. Use `Write-Host $e` -- you didn't declare that `$e` for nothing!

Comment: `foreach` and `ForEach-Object` are not the same, one is a language keyword the other is a cmdlet. `$_` is auto populated in scriptblocks that process the current object, such as in the pipeline.

Comment: Please read the `foreach` documentation. Not sure how more clear could we be. Jeroen's comment should be clear enough. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.3